# How to do this in SQL Server query instead of function?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that has a string in one of its columns.

My table look like this:

| RowCnt | Lvl | TargetID | Codes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1 | 0 | 1,1,0,1,0,1,...,1,0,0,0,0 |
| 1000 | 1 | 1 | 0,0,1,0,1,0,...,0,1,1,1,1 |
| 1000 | 1 | 2 | 1,0,0,0,1,1,...,0,0,0,0,0 |
| 1000 | 1 | 3 | 0,1,1,1,0,1,...,1,1,1,1,1 |
| 1000 | 1 | 4 | 1,1,0,0,1,0,...,0,0,1,0,0 |
| 1000 | 2 | 0 | 0,0,1,1,0,1,...,0,1,0,1,1 |
| 1000 | 2 | 1 | 0,1,0,1,1,1,...,1,1,1,1,0 |
| 1000 | 2 | 2 | 0,0,0,0,0,1,...,0,0,0,0,1 |
| 1500 | 1 | 0 | 1,1,1,1,1,0,...,1,1,1,1,0 |
| 1500 | 1 | 1 | 1,0,0,0,0,1,...,0,0,0,0,1 |

I have to compare each line with each line and see how many of digits differ in the `Codes` column.

So the first record 1,1,0,1,0,1,...,1,0,0,0,0 will be compared with the 2nd 0,0,1,0,1,0,...,0,1,1,1,1  and find that there are 14 out 328 digits different, then compare with the 3rd record 1,0,0,0,1,1,...,0,0,0,0,0 and find 29 / 328 till do all records

Then compare the 2nd record with the 3rd then the 4th and do on till do them all

My table has around 2000 records and I assume that would take around 4 million operations.

I have built a function to do the comparison

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Sim]
    (@x varchar(max),
     @y varchar(max))
RETURNS decimal(18,10)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Xt AS TABLE (id int identity, x int)
    DECLARE @Yt AS TABLE (id int identity, y int)

    DECLARE @Match int
    DECLARE @All int

    INSERT INTO @Xt (x)
        SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@x, ',')

    INSERT INTO @Yt (y)
        SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@y, ',')

    SELECT @Match = COUNT(*) 
    FROM @Xt xx 
    INNER JOIN @Yt yy ON xx.id = yy.id AND xx.x = yy.y

    SELECT @All = COUNT(*) 
    FROM @Xt xx 
    INNER JOIN @Yt yy ON xx.id = yy.id

    RETURN 1.0 * @Match / @All
END
```

and my query is like this

```
WITH Y AS (
select a.RowCnt, a.Lvl, a.TargetID a_TargetID, b.targetid b_TargetID, a.codes a_codes, b.codes b_codes, dbo.sim(a.codes, b.codes) sim
from TargetsComp A inner join TargetsComp B
    on a.RowCnt = b.RowCnt 
    and a.TargetID < b.TargetID
)


insert into TargetFilled (RowCnt, Lvl, a_TargetID, b_TargetID, a_codes, b_codes, sim)
SELECT RowCnt, Lvl, a_TargetID, b_TargetID, a_codes, b_codes, sim FROM Y ORDER BY  RowCnt,Lvl, sim desc
```

but my method fills C drive and does not finish!!

Any better way?

Comment: Is each `Codes` column the same length? What is the maximum length? Is each of the digits either `0` or `1` (that is, bits) or can they be something else?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Max length is 10,000 bit and it is only 0 or 1

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: Again: are they all the exact same length? If not what result do you want to show if they are different lengths

Comment: @Charlieface yes they are all the exact same length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A faster version of your function would be an *inline* Table Valued Function.**

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.Similar (@x varchar(max), @y varchar(max))
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN

SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN xJ.value <> yJ.value THEN 1 END) * 1.0 / COUNT(*) AS Pct
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) rn
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@x, ',')
) xJ
JOIN (
    SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) rn
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@y, ',')
) yJ ON yJ.rn = xJ.rn;
```

However, `STRING_SPLIT` with a row-number is not guaranteed to always return results in the actual order of the string. It may do it once, it may do it a million times, but there is always a chance the compiler could rearrange things. So instead you could use `OPENJSON`

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.Similar (@x varchar(max), @y varchar(max))
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN

SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN xJ.value <> yJ.value THEN 1 END) * 1.0 / COUNT(*) AS Pct
FROM OPENJSON('[' + @x + ']') xJ
JOIN OPENJSON('[' + @y + ']') yJ ON yJ.[key] = xJ.[key];
```

You would use it like this

```sql
WITH Y AS (
    select
      a.RowCnt,
      a.Lvl,
      a.TargetID a_TargetID,
      b.targetid b_TargetID,
      a.codes a_codes,
      b.codes b_codes,
      sim.Pct sim
    from TargetsComp A
    inner join TargetsComp B
        on a.RowCnt = b.RowCnt 
       and a.TargetID < b.TargetID
    CROSS APPLY dbo.sim(a.codes, b.codes) sim
)
insert into TargetFilled
  (RowCnt, Lvl, a_TargetID, b_TargetID, a_codes, b_codes, sim)
SELECT RowCnt, Lvl, a_TargetID, b_TargetID, a_codes, b_codes, sim
FROM Y;
-- you may want to add
-- WHERE sim.Pct < 100
```

I have removed the `ORDER BY` from the insert as I don't think it's necessary.

You should index your table as follows

```sql
CLUSTERED INDEX ON TargetsComp (RowCnt, TargetID)
```